# Sidebar gradient left to right but also down

Tags: html, css, colors, gradient, sidebar

I have a sidebar that I have to create that has a gradient from left to right which is fine, but it also fades out vertically as it gets to the bottom. Any idea on how to achieve this? Have looked around but can't find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you mean a diagonal gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine gradient with `mask`

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,blue);
  -webkit-mask-image:linear-gradient(white,transparent);  
  mask-image:linear-gradient(white,transparent);   
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Like below if you want a third color:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background-color:green;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,blue);
  -webkit-mask-image:linear-gradient(white,transparent);  
  mask-image:linear-gradient(white,transparent); 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this worked perfectly, had never heard of such a method. Thanks a lot!